# Post has_one gallery or Post has_many images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Still kind of new to Rails & I'm working on a cms. I've been wondering which would be the best way to give each post it's own gallery.

```
Post has_one gallery
Gallery has_many images
```

or just

```
Post has_many images
```

I'm pretty users will not want to have more than 1 gallery per post, so which one would be the best solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will greatly depends of what you want to do with galleries.

If this is only a presentation thing (images grouped within some html code to be displayed united), you don't need a Gallery model.

Now, if Gallery has actual meaning in your business logic - like if you want to add special attributes on it, like license or category - you could have a dedicated model.

The question you should ask yourself is : will galleries be used somewhat unrelated to posts ? For example, a user may want to reuse one gallery from a post in an other one. Or, you may want to allow visitors to browse galleries, without having to pass through every single post.

That's up to you. But since you're writing a tool more than a final product, I would recommend to be the more open possible : it makes sense to have a concept of gallery, so that people building third party extensions can do useful things with them.

Comment: @Oliver Wow! Such an informative answer.. I haven't even considered the possibility of making the galleries "DRY" & reusable like you mentioned.. Thank you :)